# AuthenticationHeaderValue can not be set

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, system.net

I can trying to set an authentication value just for testing purposes.
I am not using basic authentication but just a String

```
VC.Request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Secret Password");
```

It gives me this error that is making me pulling my hair off:

```
The format of value 'Secret Password' is invalid.
```

Again I don't want to use basic authentication and I don't know whats wrong, help?

Answer (score 4):

The class is ["documented"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.authenticationheadervalue(v=vs.118).aspx) as:

> Represents authentication information in Authorization, ProxyAuthorization, WWW-Authneticate[sic], and Proxy-Authenticate header values.

By calling the constructor with one parameter, you're using "Secret Password" as `scheme`, which can only contain tokens (i.e. no spaces). See [RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) for specification.

You might want to call the [other constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137974(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
new AuthenticationHeaderValue("MySuperAuthScheme", "Secret Password");
```

Answer (score -2):

I think basic authentication generally uses a `username:password` syntax, so the client-side code might be pre-validating it to stop you sending "bad" data mistakenly to the server, even though that's what you're intentionally trying to do.  Try adding a `:` and see if that helps.